# How to change header and element foreground for a data grid in WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, foreground

As I shown in bellow I have a Datagrid and  I want to change its foreground for both header style and element style Dynamically

```
var brush1 = FindResource("DgColumnElementForeground") as SolidColorBrush;
                if (brush1.IsFrozen) brush1 = brush1.Clone();
                brush1.Color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(Default.dgContentFontColor);

                var brush2 = FindResource("DgColumnHeaderForeground") as SolidColorBrush;
                if (brush2.IsFrozen) brush2 = brush2.Clone();
                brush2.Color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(Default.dgHeaderFontColor);
```

I used above code to get wanted result; but it didn't change anything.
Please, tell me what's wrong with my code.
thanks

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DgArchive" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" HorizontalAlignment="Left" KeyDown="DgArchive_OnKeyDown"
                  Height="451" Margin="11,74,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1167" IsReadOnly="True" MouseDoubleClick="DgArchive_OnMouseDoubleClick">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ArchiveID}" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Calibri"
                                    MaxWidth="0" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="کۆد" Binding="{Binding ArchiveCode}" Width="Auto">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource DgColumnHeaderForeground}" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource DgColumnElementForeground}" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="رێکەوت" Binding="{Binding ArchiveDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yyyy\}}" Width="Auto">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource DgColumnHeaderForeground}" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource DgColumnElementForeground}" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: please, can anybody help me?

Comment: There are so many problems in your code due to which you are unable to change Style Dynamically.
1) Separate all Styles from your control
2) Bind Style dynamically like Style={Binding NewStyle}